# How would i let the c# script know of a collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I have this script for this game I'm making and I'm trying to make the object that a bullet hits dissapear.. Heres my script:

```
void onCollisionEnter()
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameobject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

The error says

---

Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name 'collision' does not exist in the current context  First person game.CSharp    C:\Users\desha\Documents\First person game\Assets\Prefabs\Bullet_kill.cs    20  Active

---

It says this error twice, So if collision doesn't exist in this context, How do i get whatever the bullet collides with to disappear?

Please help.

Comment: did you try OnTriggerEnter?

Comment: It says that isn't right either.

Comment: Okay i got it to not have errors, But it still doesn't work.. I don't know the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you are missing the function input.
change this line

```
void onCollisionEnter()
```

for this one here:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
```

I hope I was of help. :)

The error appears twice because you are calling "collision" on the **if** statement, and then again on Destroy(collision.gameobject), which by the way should be **Destroy(collision.gameObject)**.

Comment: Thanks this helped alot! now im just having trouble because there is no error, However the box is still not dissapearing

Comment: I'd love to help, but i'll need more info, maybe post SS of your GameObject's inspector panel (both)? Then maybe I can help you. Colliders can be tricky, sometimes you are better off using triggers.